# Does anyone know how to access MRP Detail Inquiry results from a generic inquiry in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to find the MRP detail (or equivalent) table for a generic inquiry in Acumatica.  The element properties indicated on the Detail Inquiry page are Data Class: AMRPPlan and Business Logic: MRPDetail.  I can't find anything like these in the list of tables under Generic Inquiry.

Comment: I can't find any table with that name in the product either. Are you sure this feature is coming out-of-box in Acumatica? It looks like a customization adds those tables.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour Thanks for looking at this.  MRP is part of the JAMS manufacturing add-on from JAAS Systems.  I can see many MRP tables, but not AMRPPlan.

Comment: I had success with it, maybe you forgot to include the namespace? I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In table name column add the namespace and class name: `JAMS.MRP.AMRPPlan`

[image]

Comment: It was a simple mistake on my part. I forgot to select 'ALL RECORDS' in the table list (as opposed to 'MOST USED'). Your answer made me go back and look yet again, and I finally noticed this. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: OK I see, to avoid this error you can also directly enter the value in the textbox instead of using the selector.